# $\mathbb R$ as union of nowhere dense set and null set.

Tags: real-analysis

It is well known that $\mathbb R$ can be written as a union of a null set and a meagre set (set of first category).

Can $\mathbb R$ also be written as a union of a null set and a nowhere dense set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  If $A$ is nowhere dense, then $A^c \supset \bar{A}^c$ which is open and dense; in particular open and nonempty.  But every nonempty open set has positive measure.